# Tkinter gui stops functioning when adding frame widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Here is some code I'm using for a project, it's very bare and not functional at this point. I'm having trouble with the frame widget. Right now when I run the code nothing happens, but if I delete the lines about the frame and scrollbar, and change the listbox/canvas widget parents to "root" instead of "frame", the code works. I've looked at plenty of examples online and I don't understand why no gui window appears when I try to put everything in a frame rather than the root window...? Thanks!

Using python 2.7.

```
import pymongo
import glob, os
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("keyBuilder")
frame = Frame(root, width = 630, height = 400)

groupMenu = Listbox(frame)
groupMenu.config(width = 30)
groupMenu.insert(END, "Group 1")
groupMenu.insert(END, "Group 2")
groupMenu.insert(END, "Group 3")

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

gallery = Canvas(frame, width = 600, height = 400, yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set)

path = r'/Users/Sam/Desktop/keynoteProject/slideIcons'
COLUMNS = 6
image_count = 0

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpeg')):
    image_count += 1
    r, c = divmod(image_count-1, COLUMNS)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    resized = im.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
    myvar = Label(gallery, image=tkimage)
    myvar.image = tkimage
    myvar.grid(row=r, column=c)

groupMenu.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y)
gallery.pack(side = RIGHT)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If it's helpful, this code works:

```
import pymongo
import glob, os
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("keyBuilder")

groupMenu = Listbox(root)
groupMenu.config(width = 30)
groupMenu.insert(END, "Group 1")
groupMenu.insert(END, "Group 2")
groupMenu.insert(END, "Group 3")

gallery = Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 400)

path = r'/Users/Sam/Desktop/keynoteProject/slideIcons'
COLUMNS = 6
image_count = 0

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpeg')):
    image_count += 1
    r, c = divmod(image_count-1, COLUMNS)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    resized = im.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
    myvar = Label(gallery, image=tkimage)
    myvar.image = tkimage
    myvar.grid(row=r, column=c)

groupMenu.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y)
gallery.pack(side = RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you post the real code? You didn't assign `root` anywhere here.

Comment: My bad, missed one line when copy/pasting. Fixed!

Comment: Problem seems to be with the scrollbar. Without it, it's working fine. Seems like mixing `pack` and `grid` layout is a problem here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing `pack` and `grid` in the same container. You can only use one or the other for all widgets that share a common parent. `groupMenu`, `yscrollbar`, and `canvas` are all children of `frame`. `yscrollbar` uses `grid` but the others use `pack`.